# Google Maps Distance Matrix API Not Processing Address Array

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-apps-script

I'm very new to this so apologies if this is overly basic.

I'm trying to loop an array of addresses from a Google Sheet into the Google Maps Distance Matrix API.

Specifically, I'm trying to calculate time to destination from a fixed address in New York City.

I'm succeeding in stringifying the addresses, but can't seem to get the API to process them. Thank you very much!

```
function RunAPI (x) {   
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp
     .openById('1d_p_aHD0Nc7LpvI5P72XQ7a-LA4SkOh4T4zyJwFsrzE')
     .getSheetByName('Lunch');
  var results = sheet.getSheetValues(3, 2, sheet.getLastRow(), 1)
  results.reduce(function(a, b) {return a.concat(b);});
  var resultsstring = JSON.stringify(results);
         Logger.log(resultsstring);
  if (resultsstring =! '"'); {


  for (var x = 0; x < resultsstring.length; x++) {
    var url = UrlFetchApp.fetch('https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?units=imperial&mode=walking&origins=253+Broadway+New+York+10007&destinations='
             +encodeURIComponent(resultsstring[x])
             +'&key=KEY');
    var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url);
    return response


        }
     }
}

function runTest(){
  response = RunAPI("https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?")
  Logger.log(response)
}
```

Comment: What is the response you're getting from the server? Are you encountering any errors?

Comment: Hey Adam, not getting any errors, functions seem to run just fine. They end up logging all of the addresses as strings, doesn't seem like they're affected by the API.